# Book in which a father and daughter wake up on an abandoned spacecraft after spending hundreds of years in cryostasis

Tags: story-identification, novel, space, cryogenics

I read a book a while ago about a father and daughter who were cryogenically frozen until the cure for the daughter's disease was found. But it turns out they were frozen for hundreds of years and are now on an abandoned spacecraft.

That’s where my memory starts to haze on the rest.  I read it in 2016, maybe 2017, and the cover was a man fighting some alien I think. I just remember it being super good and would love to read it again.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I’d say I read it like 2016 maybe 17 and the cover was a man fighting some alien I think